# How to know/change buffer size in fuse readdir function?

Tags: c, fuse

I'm writing the `readdir` function for a FUSE file system in Linux. My idea is to put an arbitrary number of directory entries in the buffer, to keep low the number of `getdents` syscalls from external programs when listing a directory (avoiding a call for each file).

The buffer argument of the function is provided by FUSE, along with the pointer to a `filler` helper function of type `fuse_fill_dir_t` that knows how to handle this buffer.

The problem is that I don't know how to get or change the size of this buffer, and the `filler` function returns **1** when the buffer is full.

Note that I'm using an offset to call the `filler` function, using a **0** isn't an option, as I don't want to return all the directory entries in just one `getdents` call.

```
filler(buf, d->d_name, NULL, next_offset);
```

Testing throws a **102** fixed maximum number of entries for the buffer, but I don't want to rely on "magical" numbers, and I don't know where this number comes from.

Comment: Well, finally I went for the trial and error method. I put entries into the buffer using the `filler` function until it's full and returns 1. Due to my implementation of directory entries offsets, I need to remember the last entry retrieved to insert it into the next `readdir` call to FUSE. I can't control the buffer size, but at least I'm minimizing the number of calls to `getdents` from programs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `getdents()` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) the buffer is supplied by the calling application:

> **getdents()**
>
> ```
>    The system call getdents() reads several linux_dirent structures from
>    the directory referred to by the open file descriptor fd into the
>    buffer pointed to by dirp.  The argument count specifies the size of
>    that buffer.
> ```

Thus the number of `getdents()` syscalls is going to be determined by the application doing the call.

Comment: Yes, you are right about `getdents`. But I need to know the size of this buffer from FUSE, and all the information comes from the arguments of the `readdir` function. The type of the buffer argument of the `readdir` function is `void *`, but reading the FUSE source code I can see that it's a `struct fuse_dh *`.

Comment: Plus almost all programs use the `readdir` function from glibc instead of directly calling `getdents`.